# logging the rest calls

Tags: facebook, logging, ads

I am using group: 'com.facebook.ads.sdk', name: 'facebook-java-ads-sdk', version: '0.4.0'

On com.dan.dadl.ccr.process.facebook.APIContext there is method setLogger(PrintStream logger)

By default this logs to System.out

I would like to log the rest calls to the application's log. The application is using log4j2.

Can anyone advise me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To do it you need change the `system.out PrintStream`. You need the next code lines to do it.

```
public String getLoggerFileName() {
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger loggerImpl = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) log;
    Appender appender = loggerImpl.getAppenders().get("FileAppender");
    // Unfortunately, File is no longer an option to return, here.
    return ((FileAppender) appender).getFileName();
}

final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(WebApplicationInitializer.class);
```

On static block or entry point of your app you need to add these lines:

```
 //redirect sysout to log
    File file = new File(getLoggerFileName());
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        System.setOut(ps);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So, all output by `System.out.println` will be redirected to file.